# How to post a javascript function into a html input field

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have longitude and latitude inside the input form, but I cannot figure out how to do it, I have tried a few examples, as seen in the below code (doesnt work).

```
<script>
function data(){

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = 
  "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
   "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
}</script>

<form name="test_form">
  <input id="demo" type="text" value=""> 
</form>
<button onclick="getLocation();">GO</button>
```

Expected results:
Longitude and Latitude to be inside the input box, or if possible, longitude in one input box, latitude in anoter

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This is a good  question! well done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Markup

```
<input id="lat" type="text" value=""> 
<input id="long" type="text" value=""> 
<button onclick="getLocation();">GO</button>
```

JS

```
function getLocation(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var coordinates = position.coords;
        document.getElementById('lat').value = coordinates.latitude;
        document.getElementById('long').value = coordinates.longitude;
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value of the input instead of overriding its HTML.

like

`// set the value of the input
 x.value = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ...`

**Updated to include separate boxes for Lat/Lon**

See demo below

```js
function showPosition(position) {
  console.log('location obtained');
  console.log(position);

  var lon = document.getElementById("lon");
  var lat = document.getElementById("lat");

  // set the value of the inputs
  lon.value = position.coords.longitude;
  lat.value = position.coords.latitude;
}

function getLocation() {
  console.log('button clicked');

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log('getting location');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>Longitud:</label><input id="lon" type="text" value=""> <br/>
<label>Latitude:</label><input id="lat" type="text" value=""> <br/>
<button onclick="getLocation();">GO</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `x.value =`  instead of its innerHTML.